# Problem mounting NFS shares from OSX servers

Tags: macos, terminal, network, nfs

I am having a  problem using NFS connecting to shares **from** a Mac with Catalina and another one with Snow Leopard (don't ask why ;). I just updated to BigSur 11.4 When I use :

`-fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc`

in `/etc/auto_nfs`

```
cd /System/Volumes/Data/NetVolumes/data
-bash: cd: /System/Volumes/Data/NetVolumes/data: Invalid argument
```

if by other hand I use

`-fstype=nfs,rw,sync`

```
cd /System/Volumes/Data/NetVolumes/data1
-bash: cd: /System/Volumes/Data/NetVolumes/data1: RPC prog. not avail
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am posting a solution here since I got the mounts to work. I had followed a suggestion had added version=4 in /etc/nfs.conf which was the culprit.  once I commented that, I can mount shares from catalina and snow leopard with both sets of options work